# How to target div when neither specificity nor important work

Tags: html, css

I have a div class`.shelter` which I'm trying to target. However `specificity` and `important` don't work.

Initially It worked when I tried.

```
.shelter{text-align: center; font-size :20px; font-weight: 
bold}
```

This worked to target the div but as soon as I added:

```
`color: #e6d40e !important;`
```

It didn't work anymore.

So I tried specificity:

```
.entry-content>.blog>.shelter{text-align: center; font-size 
:20px; font-weight: bold; color: #e6d40e !important;}
```

Didn't work.

Html:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="unfortunately">This is, unfortunately, the 
Adsler blog.<link 
href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Anton&#038;display=swap" rel="stylesheet">. 
</div>
<p></p><div class="blog"><embed style="width: 100%; 
height: 500px;" src="https://www.kw-berlin.de/" 
width="300" height="150"></embed></p><div 
class="shelter"><a href 
="https://www.shelter.org.uk/">Making sure no one has 
to fight bad housing or homelessness on their own</a>. 
</div>
<p></br></p>
```

Page [here](https://adsler.co.uk/adsler-blog/)

Comment: **but** the color won't work because it's **link** you want to style, not base text. You need `.shelter a`. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/YzKVxzm

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Do you mind my asking why I can style everything except color with just`.shelter`?

Comment: The `a` tag's color is specified by other css styling and if not then at least it gets the color from the browser's default stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
.shelter a{ color: #e6d40e; }
```